# Is it possible to have one LINQ in one line of code for

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In the method below I want to return an array of indices of selected cards:

```
public class Card
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    // ... other members here ...
}

public void int[] GetSelectedCards(Cards[] cards)
{ 
    // return cards.Where(c => c.Selected).ToArray();   

    // above line is not what I want, I need their indices
}
```

Does anyone know a nice one line of code LINQ for that? Possible?

**Update:**

Interesting, I found also something:

```
return cards.Where(c => c.Selected).Select(c => Array.IndexOf(cards, c));
```

What do you think?

Comment: Technically, you can write entire class in one line regardless of statements counts?

Comment: *Interesting, I found also something* This will work but it's slower than the overload of Select.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the overload of [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which projects the element's index to initialize an anonymous type:

```
return cards
    .Select((c, i) => new { Card = c, Index = i})
    .Where(x => x.Card.Selected)
    .Select(x => x.Index)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: from first Select @Cristi

Comment: @Cristi: i've edited the answer to provide the link to `Enumerable.Select`. It projects the index of each element in the sequence. `Enumerable.Where` has also this overload but it's not helpful here since you want to get that index, so you need to persist it in the anonymous type.

Comment: Now I get it :) ... could you tell if my finding (in the edit) is a lot worse than your answer? Thanks

Comment: @Cristi: your approach using `Array.IndexOf` works also but it's less efficient since it needs a second loop to find that index what my approach already has. You can translate my query to a single loop and yours to a loop which needs a second loop on every selected card.